# How restoreCompletedTransactions returns product ids,Is its as per apple id or as per application

Tags: iphone, ios5, in-app-purchase

I am developing a application in which i have 10 items setup for in-app purchase, and also i am giving an option to restore the purchases he made, if user changes his device or may be any possible case.

I want to ask that, if user taps on "restore transactions" button from my application,then Store kit is going to return all the purchases id from  his Apple id(that he purchased from other apps also) or it will return  only of my application.

From the Test Account it returns only of my application purchases ids,But if i try with my apple id, but its giving me error: "This is not a Test User account.",I guess i cannot test restoreCompletedTransactions in debug mode.

So i wanted to know how its going to return the purchases id if the app is released.

Can any one help me..
Thanx...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It returns only the purchased products that belong to your application both in the sandbox mode and production mode.